# Scope of variable session on POST method in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The req.session.myvar = 'a value' in POST method in node.js with express.js seems to have just a local scope. I can't get the req.session.myvar value from other methods. But if I save the value in a GET method the scope seems to have o globar scope. I need to POST method do the same.

```
var express  = require('express'),
port     = 3000;
var app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser(''));
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'secret'}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.post('/create', function(req, res) {
   req.session.firstName = 'jhon';
   console.log(req.session);
});


app.get('/create', function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.session);
   req.session.lastName = 'Doe';
   res.render('create');
});


app.post('/create_occur', function(req, res) {
   console.log('/create_occur');
   console.log(req.session);
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
```

This is the simply .ejs that I was using to do tests.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/socket.io.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>        
        <section>
            <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title">
            <input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Enviar">
        </section>       
        <section>
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Nombre">
            <input type="submit" id="nombre" value="Nombre">
        </section>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {                

                $("#enviar").click(function() {
                    var title = $('#title').val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url:  '/create',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {'title': title}
                    });
                });               

                $("#nombre").click(function() {
                    var name = $('#name').val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url:  '/create_occur',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {'title': name}
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Help me please, I don't understand why this happens. I see several examples similar in blogs and videos and they do this and works.

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out finally!! It's a silly problem/forgotten. I was to add a line to response the request:

```
res.end();
```

Or:

```
res.redirect('/');
```

Bye, I hope this can help.